# A property of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Why if a sequence $a_{n}\rightarrow + \infty$, then it can't be that ${\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\rightarrow 0 }$? Thanks!

Comment: What is (are) your idea(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \to 0$, then at some point $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$, $\forall n>n_0$.

Thus $a_n$ is a decreasing sequence... Which can't go to $\infty$.

EDIT: of course I take $a_n>0$ here, but you can take the absolute value anyway...

Comment: Thanks! Can I also ask very similar question? Why if $a_{n}$ converges, than it must be that $\frac{a_{n+a}}/{a_{n}}$ also converges if $a_{n}$ does not $\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: If the answer is to your liking, you can aaccept it (on the left hand side). For your other question: suppose that $a_n$ converge to $L$. It means that it will be closer and closer to $L$, and it will mean that $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ will get closer and closer to $\dfrac LL=1$.

Comment: I can accept the answer only after some time. Does your answer means, that it is always $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\rightarrow 1$ and not other real numbers? Maybe they can converge with different speed?

Comment: @dart_kaide They can't. $a_{n+1}$ is the following term after $a_n$. Convergence states that each consecutive elements of the sequence are closer and closer together. There is no "convergence at different speed" concept for the same sequence. This would defeat the very principle of convergence.

Comment: But still, if $a_{n}\rightarrow 0$  it can be the case that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\rightarrow \infty$ or other real numbers. So it does not defeat the principle of convergence. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @dart_kaide You are right that $a_n \to 0$ is a special case. For instance take $a_n=(-\frac 12)^n$. Then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=-\frac{1}{2}$. But if $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \to a$, $\mid a \mid >1$, then you have a diverging sequence.